# how make a windows link to directory that contains a % (href)

Tags: hyperref

I've been trying to make a link to this directory

`href{%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start}{Start Items}`

But everything following % is considered to be a comment.

Is it possible to make it work?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[autolanguage]{numprint}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage[letterpaper, left=1.25in, right=1.25in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem} % Use for advanced enum-list functionality
\usepackage[os=mac, mackeys=symbols]{menukeys}
% DÉBUT Option lien \href
\hypersetup{
bookmarksopen=true,
bookmarksnumbered=true,
pdfdisplaydoctitle=true,
unicode=false,          % non-Latin characters in Acrobat’s bookmarks
pdftoolbar=false,        % show Acrobat’s toolbar?
pdfmenubar=true,        % show Acrobat’s menu?
pdffitwindow=false,     % window fit to page when opened
pdfstartview={FitV},    % the page to the window
pdftitle={\titre},    % title
pdfauthor={\auteur},     % author
pdfsubject={\cour},  % subject of the document
pdfcreator={\departement},   % creator of the document
pdfproducer={\cegep}, % producer of the document
% pdfkeywords={}, % list of keywords
pdfnewwindow=true,      % links in new PDF window
frenchlinks=true,
pdfborder={0 0 0}
% colorlinks=false,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
%linkcolor=blue,          % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
%citecolor=green,        % color of links to bibliography
%filecolor=magenta,      % color of file links
%urlcolor=blue           % color of external links}
% FIN Option lien \href  

% [...]  

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Ouvrir l'explorateur de fichiers Windows
    \item Aller au dossier de démarrage. Copier ce chemin d'accès dans l'explorateur Windows: \\
   \%AppData\%\textbackslash Microsoft\textbackslash Windows\textbackslash Start Menu\textbackslash Programs\textbackslash Startup
    \item Clic-droit, Créer un nouveau raccourci
    \item Coller la ligne de commande que vous avez préalablement copier depuis RealTimeSync
    \item Suivant, OK
    \item La synchronisation se fera dès que l'ordinateur détecte votre clé usb.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace each occurrence of `%` with `\%`?

Comment: i've tried, it doesn't work,  it prints right but the hyperlink doesn't work

Comment: B.t.w. welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: `%APPDATA%` is the syntax for referencing an environment variable in a shell under Windows. But environment variables do not work in URLs, because the path specifications are read by a PDF viewer as simple strings and not interpreted by a shell. The correct full path is needed and backslashes are replaced by forward slashes.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek
The file path i'm obtaining is this:
`C:\User\Maxime\AppData\Roaming`
Can i modifiy it to:
`C:\User\Username\AppData\Roaming`

Comment: @imtaurus94 `file:///C|/User/Username/AppData/Roaming/...`